# Syrian partner refused visit visa for UK

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, syrian-citizens

I was recommended this forum by my brother and I really hope someone can help! I really don’t know how to start…

My partner applied for a 6 month UK visit visa and it was refused on paragraphs. V2 (A) and (C) Most of the points raised were about his financial status, although they were happy he worked full time he had a few discrepancies which were not declared, mostly moving savings around, lending money to friends and general life costs (rent, electricity etc) After some research I believe we have indirectly been refused on suspected ‘funds parking’ so we are aware on the next application to be completely transparent surrounding his bank statements and try to accurately demonstrate where his money is coming from and where it’s going. However it’s hard to prove this as lots of companies in the UAE do not provide payslips, we did however get a salary certificate and contract from his work which UKVI were satisfied with however it did not accurately demonstrate where the other money had come from. Is it worth marking and highlighting on the bank statements we provide to eliminate any discrepancies?

The second point raised was on sponsorship. As we are a couple we split costs especially with me travelling to the UAE we split flight costs, hotels and general holiday expenses they stated that I had not said on the invitation letter that I would split costings (I had said this just less black and white) I currently stay at home and my parent is happy for him to stay with us whilst in the UK and provided their own payslip. However the response we received was the dreaded “this sponsorship does not satisfy me of your own intention to leave the UK” We provided contracts of work and car ownership, he is not a home owner.

[image]

[image]

He is a Syrian national however he has sponsored residency in the UAE and has done for about 18 years. He has travelled to Europe and never overstayed his visa and has proof of this on his current passport and his previous passport. He lives with his family in the UAE so not only has to return for work commitments but also family commitments as he is one of the main breadwinners.

He works full time in the UAE and in addition to this he works on major events for extra income (which is declared) He and I both work time and would like to continue to do so in our respective countries, certainly until we decide to take the relationship further which is why we applied for the visit visa.

He and I met in November 2017 and decided to give a long-term relationship a go! I returned to the UAE in January for work, then I also visited in May only to see him. During this time we decided to apply for the 6month visit visa as I had a family occasion I wanted my boyfriend to attend have a 2 week holiday and then return to the UAE. Unfortunately the visit was refused. Overall I will have been to the UAE 5 times this year to visit him and keep our relationship going.

Although I am very fortunate that I can take the required annual leave it does make me very sad that my partner cannot visit my home country and meet my friends and family. I also work full time in the UK for a part governmental agency so I also have work commitments.

I do understand our situation is relatively complexed and we will have to seek legal advice, but I really appreciate any and all advice!

Here are all the documents we provided – My bank statements, my savings statement, my payslip, my passport, my letter of sponsorship, my previous visit flight details, my parents payslip, hotel booking, His bank statements, his car ownership documents, his work contract, his salary certificate, his annual leave confirmation, his passports (Old and new) and his provisional flight details.

So my questions are –

1. Should we apply again for the visit visa?

1.2 If we do should it be a longer visit visa (2yrs, 5yrs) and setting out our plans in black and white justify our intentions of holidaying in eachother’s countries before eventually deciding to settle in either the UK or UAE?

1.3 How else can we prove he will leave the UK?

1.4 Should I act as a sponsor or let him apply solo and rely on his own funds?

2. Are there specialist immigration lawyers who have worked with Syrian nationals previously? Who are they?
3. Are there other routes should I consider? (Me moving to the UAE?)
4. Are there any other documents we may not have thought about which could support his application?

All help is massively appreciated! Happy to answer any questions on this!

Comment: Q1 Don’t reapply quickly unless you can address all the refusal reasons. As you’ve already recognised in your question, your partner needs to simplify his financial background so it’s easier for the ECO to understand. Can he provide tax returns showing he’s declared his additional Income? Q1.2 A long term visit visa application isn’t a good idea immediately after a refusal, it could raise suspicions of immigrant intent and without a strong U.K. travel history is more likely to be refused. Q1.3 Can he demonstrate dependents in UAE? Who owns/rents the property where he lives?

Comment: Q1 - Noted, I'm not 100% it would be a tax return but potentially a document from the events company to show ho much he earned? 
Q1.2 - Noted We did consider this we just weren't sure whether it would make our situation clearer like "we've applied for the 2 year visa because we're not jumping into this and we would like the option to visit each other before making more serious decisions about settling" 
Q1.3-His father rents the property, but works out of the UAE so he is technically 'head of the house' He lives their with his siblings, one of which has 2 children. Not dependant technically

Comment: Hi ans welcome @Kels. Please read the information contained in the linked duplicate and then ask a new question which addresses the points not covered by the duplicate.